How to navigate into an already downloaded WASM application?
Let's say you are using the Hosted Web App template for Blazor. The user navigates to your application and the server pre-renders the page, and then the WASM is loaded and takes over as expected.
The next time you navigate to the same URL in the browser, is there a way to respond to the browser that it should use the WASM application that was already downloaded rather than pre-rendering the page on the backend again and having the browser download the WASM all over again?
As I was typing this, I recalled having seen some documentation for a PWA flavor of Blazor. I checked it out and it does check the box in regard to the goal of wanting the application to load faster. However, it otherwise seems overkill as I really don't need the other features it offers.

There is not much 'overkill'. Just don't register the serviceworker  (or use the developer version).

@HenkHolterman At first glance the documentation for a PWA seemed to look like it required significant changes, but at second glance maybe most of it is just explaining how it works and the actual changes are more minimal that I thought. Can you say, if I don't use the serviceworker, will it prevent allowing the user to download the application or could I otherwise disable this... I only want them to access in a browser but just with the "cache first" strategy.
